# Autoclicker on specified time

Tags: click

I need to have autoclicker, which clicks on mouse on specified time. For example, when it's 12:00 (windows time), the cursor clicks.

Do you know any autoclicker, which could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you would do this in Python (this same basic structure should apply to whatever you are using) of a program that clicks between the times Noon to 1 PM.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time

mouse = Controller()
loop = True

while loop == True:
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = str(now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    current_time = int(current_time.replace(":", ""))
    if 120000 < current_time < 130000:
        #mouse.position = (x, y) // to click on a specific pixel
        mouse.click(Button.left)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```